# Allowing user to create new data types with custom properties

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, software-design

I am working on a web project where the user should be able to create custom types of merchandise containing any amount of properties of different types (numbers, text, etc). E.g: a box, which has name, price and physical dimensions, and a bottle, which has name, price, and volume.

What would be the best way to represent this in code and in the database?
My first idea was to create a basic template for a piece of merchandise, and dump all the custom data in a single field as stringified JSON. The downside is that this data couldn't be used for IQueryable search, filtering, sorting.

I can also think of creating a separate table, in which I'd store all the custom fields of all merchandise, and referencing them via relations. Wouldn't this, however, cause problems with scaling, as I will be essentially storing all custom properties everywhere in a single table.

Is in the best way to do it? There is no way to create new classes and database tables on the fly in .NET Core, of course, but what other options there are?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: I would compare existing eCommerce solutions and would pick most convenient or elegant solution (to avoid inventing the wheel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing this in my current side project, and I've done it in the past as well. Basically, you will have a base `Product` table (or whatever you want to name it). Then you also have tables such as `ProductAttributeType` and `ProductAttribute`.

The base `Product` table would contain attributes common to all products, such as `Name` and `Price`.

**ProductAttributeType**

```sql
ProductAttributeTypeCode VARCHAR(10)
AttributeTypeName        VARCHAR(50)
```

Where `ProductAttributeTypeCode` contains a short / abbreviated code for the attribute type (e.g. "BOOL"), and `AttributeTypeName` is a friendly name (e.g. "Boolean" or "Yes/No").

**ProductAttribute**

```sql
ProductId                INT          -- Foreign key to Product table
ProductAttributeTypeCode VARCHAR(10)  -- Foreign key to ProductAttributeType table
AttributeName            VARCHAR(100) -- The name of the product attribute (e.g. "Volume")
AttributeValue           VARCHAR(MAX) -- Contains the actual value of the product attribute
```

`Product` has a one-to-many relationship with `ProductAttribute`.

This is the approach I've taken in the past, as well as in a current project, and it works pretty well. It appears to be a pretty common approach for solving this sort of problem. The only "downside" I can think of is that you need to make sure that the value in the `ProductAttribute.AttributeValue` column matches the appropriate type for `ProductAttributeType(Code)`. If you design your code properly, and it's well thought out, it's really not so bad, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is, more or less the idea I had too, but the separate table for types is undoubtedly an improvement. The only question I've left is how can the ProductAttribute.AttributeValue property match the appropriate type, if it is actually stored as VARCHAR? Do you mean it should be checked and converted appropriately in the code?

Comment: @Valhaal yes, you would need to ensure in code that the appropriate value is stored in `ProductAttribute.AttributeValue`. When retrieving the data from the table, you can then convert to the primitive type (e.g. `bool`, `int`, etc) as needed.

Comment: Got it, thank you for your help. Marking question as answered.